No module named 'awsgluedq'
I am trying to run aws glue script in local docker environment
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsgluedq.transforms import EvaluateDataQuality

I have imports as above. All imports works except awsgluedq
It throws error as ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awsgluedq'
Command to execute glue script
docker run -it -v ~/.aws:/home/glue_user/.aws -v $WORKSPACE_LOCATION:/home/glue_user/workspace/ -e AWS_PROFILE=$PROFILE_NAME -e DISABLE_SSL=true --rm -p 4040:4040 -p 18080:18080 --name glue_spark_submit amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_4.0.0_image_01-arm64 spark-submit /home/glue_user/workspace/src/$SCRIPT_FILE_NAME

As per documentation for awsgluedq glue version 3 or later should be used. But glue version is 4. Whats wrong here?
Thanks in advance

There has been an Issue raised in the official aws-glue-libs library that awsgluedq is unavailable in the glue 4.0 image. Your best bet is to downgrade to 3.x.
AWSGlueDQ not available in glue 4.0 image

even downgrading didnt work
